# Intercepting post data from WebView on android 4.1-4.3 when server is on TLS 1.2

Tags: android, webview, tls1.2

We have a server that is using TLS 1.2. This causes issues with loading the URL on Android devices 4.1-4.3. Loading the URL on any device 4.4+, everything works fine.

So to enable the url, I have implemented `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` in the `WebViewClient`. When I detect the URL, I make a call via the OkHTTP library that I have setup to use TLS 1.2.

The issue is on this URL, there is a form that posts to a URL on the same server a username and password. I am having trouble correctly calling this authentication URL.

I have overridden the `shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url)` method and when I detect the URL that it is posting to is the one I want, I intercept the request and make the call using my OKHttp client that is setup to use the TLS 1.2 and return a `WebResourceResponse` object with the response.

The problem is I do not have access to the data in the form to send along to this url, so validation is always failing.

Is there a way I can get the POST data from this (or any other method inside the `WebViewClient` class? Is there a better way to load a page on a server that is using TLS 1.2 in Android versions 4.1-4.3?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What does this have to do with the server? I understand you cannot intercept the data that is posted by the webview when the submit button is pressed? And is this depending on the Android version?

Comment: So the server will only allow the device to connect over the TLS 1.2 protocol (which is available in Android 4.1-4.3, but just not on by default like in Android 4.4). So I have overridden the method `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` which allows me to make a call over TLS 1.2 and return the response to the WebView. The problem now is I need to make a most to a PHP page on that same server, so that means I need to do a similar thing (override a method in the `WebViewClient`, connect with OKHTTP via TLS 1.2, and return the response of that post). But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: `which allows me to make a call over TLS 1.2 and return the response to the WebView.` Ok. You can. `connect with OKHTTP via TLS 1.2, and return the response of that post). But I don't know how to do that` ? It's unclear to me why you can't anymore. And you did not react on my comment: `you cannot intercept the data that is posted by the webview when the submit button is pressed?`.

Comment: `similar thing (override a method ` Well would not that be shouldOverrideUrlLoading too?

Comment: When you make a post request, `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is not triggered. 

Yes, I cannot intercept the data when the submit button is pressed. These PHP pages on the server are not under my control and I cannot add any javascript or anything to tie into the app.

Comment: Hi! Have you solved this problem with post?

Comment: Unfortunately not. This was for a previous job and I can't remember exactly what happened with it. Sorry!